# Entity Framework Members for Posts

Tags: entity-framework, include

I am trying to program a simple forum. I want to fetch the posts for a topic and members who made those posts. Obviously the members might be duplicated if they posted more than once in the topic.

I was thinking about using Include("Members"), but does that involve duplicating Members?

Comment: db.Posts.Include("Member").Where(x => x.TopicId == topicid).ToList();

Comment: I believe yes, can you not try separating the queries. Also please refer this post on similar topic. http://mikee.se/Archive.aspx/Details/entity_framework_pitfalls,_include_20140101

Comment: Thanks for the link - interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select all the `Members` and use `Distinct`

```
var posts = db.Posts.Include("Member").Where(x=>.....).ToList();
var members = posts.Select(x=>x.Member).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I was asking for, but it's something I can use as well.